# Swagger OpenApi Spec - Empty value in GET - "Parameters" -> "Items" -> "array"

Tags: swagger, openapi

I've a parameter `quality` like this:

```
get:
  parameters:
    - name: quality
      description: Filter by "origin.quality" by comma separated value (i.e. AA,AB,BC).
      explode: false
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          enum: [EE, AA, AB, AC, AD, BA, BB, BC, BD, CA, CB, CC, CD, DA, DB, DC, DD]
```

and the Swagger returns:
[image]

The problem is that when I select the first option, `--`, the `GET` value contains `quality=` (empty value) and the back-end returns an error because the `quality` is empty. Is there a way to remove the `quality` parameter from the `GET` when `--` is selected?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 2024-01-02**: I found an issue, about it, here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5176